# Is it possible to share the Apollo cache in React Native and iOS/Android?

Tags: apollo, apollo-client, apollo-ios, apollo-android

If I build an app that has both React Native and native (iOS/Android) views, is it possible to make Apollo use a single unified cache to store the normalized data? This would be extremely useful to make sure the data is consistent across views, and it would help avoid double-fetching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently no but we are working on an implementation. Here's a recent article on what is planned https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/one-graphql-client-for-javascript-ios-and-android-64993c1b7991